# How to change the value to NA based on the other conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with many columns and rows with many ids, for example the following data only with 2 ids.

```
    id  group   time    gene1   gene2   gene3   …
1   1   A        1       1       2       2      …
2   1   A        2       2       5       4      …
3   1   A        3       3       8       5      …
4   1   A        4       3       8       6      …
5   1   A        5       3       8       7      …
6   1   B       -2       0       0       9      …
7   1   B        1       0       1       1      …
8   1   B        5       7       5       0      …
9   2   A        1       1       2       2      …
10  2   A        2       2       5       3      …
11  2   A        3       3       4       4      …
12  2   A        4       4       3       3      …
13  2   A        5       6       0       6      …
14  2   B       -2       0       0       8      …
15  2   B        1       1       0       1      …
16  2   B        5       7       5       0      …
```

I want to replace the value with NA based on the following conditions, in each subject(id):

- If the values in both of rows 6 and 7 (group B with time -2 and 1) are 0, then

  1. if the value in row 5 (group A at time 5) is 0, all the values for this subject are given NA;
  2. If the value in row 5 is not 0, values *except row 5 to row 8* are given NA.
- If the values in either of row 6 and 7 are not 0, there is no need to change any values.

---

So the output table would look like this:

```
    id  group   time    gene1   gene2   gene3   …
1   1   A        1       NA      2       2      …
2   1   A        2       NA      5       4      …
3   1   A        3       NA      8       5      …
4   1   A        4       NA      8       6      …
5   1   A        5       3       8       7      …
6   1   B       -2       0       0       9      …
7   1   B        1       0       1       1      …
8   1   B        5       7       5       0      …
9   2   A        1       1       NA      2      …
10  2   A        2       2       NA      3      …
11  2   A        3       3       NA      4      …
12  2   A        4       4       NA      3      …
13  2   A        5       6       NA      6      …
14  2   B       -2       0       NA      8      …
15  2   B        1       1       NA      1      …
16  2   B        5       7       NA      0      …
```

Comment: ``(2) if the value in row 3 is not 0, all the values except row 3 and row 6 are given NA.`` given this in `id==1` and `gene1` rows 4 and 5 also should have been `NA`. But they are still 0. Did you mean *except row 3 to row 6* translated to changing only row 1 and 2?

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Yes, it is ok for me if you can just change row 1 and 2 to NA in this condition? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very difficult to tell what you want based on the rules that you've outlined- but I'll try to follow your logic:

```
for(i in unique(df$id)){
    df_sub=df[df$id==i,] # isolate each part of df with the same id
    for(g in c('gene1','gene2','gene3')){ # treat each gene column separately
             if(df_sub[6,colnames(df_sub)==g]==0 | df_sub[7,colnames(df_sub)==g]==0){ # check if row 6 or 7 are 0
                 if(df_sub[5,colnames(df_sub)==g]==0){ #check if row 5 is 0
                      df_sub[,colnames(df_sub)==g]=NA # fulfil row 3 rule #1
                 }else{
                      df_sub[c(1:4),colnames(df_sub)==g]=NA # fulfil row 3 rule #2
                 }
             } else{print('row 6 and 7 are not both 0- no need to change')}
        }
        df[df$id==i,]=df_sub # reset values in original data frame with those from the amended 'df_sub'
    }
```

UPDATED- I hope this code is making sense

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I ran the code above, why some error as below happened. "Error in if (df_sub[6, colnames(df_sub) == s] == 0 & df_sub[7, colnames(df_sub) ==  : 
  argument is of length zero"

Comment: Hi, @Bio_farmer - I'm a bit confused- in the example data- there are 6 rows with `id == 1` and 6 with `id == 2`, hence there will not be a '7th' row in either case.. in the code in your comment above- it says `df_sub[7, ...]` this row will not exist as df_sub will only have 6 rows...

Maybe the example data that you have supplied in your question is not representative of the actual problem you're having... if you update the example data then maybe we can work on an answer a bit more??

Comment: Hi @which_command, I have updated the data for example. The code I tried was replaced with the row number in your code.

Comment: @Bio_farmer updated my answer- I hope that the code makes sense to you. If not- you can ask.

Comment: Hi, may I ask one more question based on the data example, how can I select the column, which contains "0" <= a percentage, for example 20%? The column of gene 1 and gene 3 will be selected.

Comment: use `apply` to go across the columns and check the count of 0's as a percentage: `columnwise_percentages=apply(df_sub[,4:ncol(df_sub)],2,function(x){sum(x=='0')/length(x)})`. This will return a vector of percentages and then you need to select the df_sub columns that have more than 20% '0s'- `gene_columns=df_sub[,4:ncol(df_sub)]; gene_columns[,columnwise_percentages>0.2]`